# Bootstrap Accordion - start all closed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

So I have a bootstrap style accordion on my page - but on start, the first panel is open.
How can i make it so that when you load the page, they are all closed?

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks so much!

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1"><i class="fa fa-minus text-primary"></i> Overview</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Utilities</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Organization</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel4"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Integrations</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel5"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Essentials</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel6"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Sales</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel7"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Support</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel8"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Projects</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All you need to do is remove the "in" class from the #panel1 element. Then add "collapsed" class to the corresponding button

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Boostrap 3**

Just remove `.in` from panel1.

```
<div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
   <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 1</div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4**

See [@Syed Sajid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837620/5508690)'s answer

Answer (score 30):

Bootstrap 4 and 4+ remove class `show` from `collapse show`

```
<div class="collapse">
    <div class="card-body"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 30):

For **Bootstrap 5** you also need to collapse the button else while the body won't show, the heading will still be highlighted and the icon indicating the card is open will still display.

Default is;

```
<button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
</button>
```

You need to add `collapsed` to the button & tell `aria` it's not expanded like this;

```
<button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Heading Text
</button>
```

Then the body can be dealt with as normal by removing `show` from `class="accordion-collapse collapse show"`

```
<div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
 <div class="accordion-body">
  Body Text
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful for the other way around. I thought the default was to have one open, but apparently not. So I just added `collapse show` to the body and set the `aria-expanded` to be true and collapse is already there to toggle it.

Answer (score 10):

Bootstrap 5:

add class `collapsed` to `accordion-button`

```
<button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    Accordion Item
</button>
```

remove class `show` from `accordion-collapse`

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">content...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also need to add `aria-expanded="false"` it would seem.

Answer (score 3):

With Boostrap 4, the collapse is closed by default. If you want it to show the content on page load, you can simply add the class `show`:

```
<div class="collapse">...</div>  //Content is hidden on page load

<div class="collapse show">...</div>  //Content is shown on page load
```

As per [Bootstrap 4 documention](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/):

- `.collapse` hides content
- `.collapse.show` shows content

Answer (score -1):

you must add, in the header

```
aria-expanded="true"
```

and, in the body

```
class="collapse show"
```